# How to crop half the page of an existing PDF?

Tags: pdftex, crop

I have a PDF document that was improperly scanned, so that the content (images) only occupies the top half of the portrait page.

I'd like to crop all the pages, to remove the empty bottom half, and produce a new PDF, that would thus be in landscape format.

How do I do that using pdflatex?

I tried, one at a time:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=\8.27in,paperheight=\5.85in]{geometry}
\includepdf[pages=1-,trim=1in 10in 1in 1in,clip]{myfile.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1-,trim=1in 10in 1in 1in,clip,landscape]{myfile.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1-,viewport=0 0 5in 5in]{myfile.pdf}
```

among other things, but nothing works. The best I got so far is that the content is cropped, but the page is not resized.

Comment: What length is `\8.27in` ? (with the backslash)

Comment: @Fran I have no clue, just copied it from somewhere.

Comment: But obviously wrong.  Instead of type "a bit more than eight and a quarter inches" (i.e. 8.27in)  you set the command `\8` with a  argument of 0.27 inches to make absolutely nothing, because `\8` is  an undefined control sequence (i.e., a non existing command) that  produce a fatal error.

Comment: You can use Gwenview ( a linux graphic program ) to crop your document and do a lot more with your document.

Comment: @Fran ok, thank you. Actually I had tried with and without the `\`, but simply got different errors.

Comment: @user25406 I don't see how Gwenview manage PDF files.

Comment: You can take a screen picture of the pdf page you want to crop. Then you open it with Gwenview and you will be able to crop it. Post the page you want to crop and I will crop it.

Comment: @Rodrigo Different errors because there are also *another* mistakes that we cannot guess without see your code. You can check that a minimal  working example (MWE) as `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[paperwidth=8.27in, paperheight=5.85in]{geometry} \begin{document} foo \end{document}` will work perfectly.  If you are unsure of what are you doing, always check that every single package and/or command works as expected in a MWE before of make a big mess of code hard to debug.

Comment: @Fran My code was indeed small, since I was only cropping an existing PDF. Anyway, my problem is solved now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the fitpaper option. If you have different trim values you should use a \includepdf command for each.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[fitpaper,pages=-,trim=2cm 2cm 2cm 1cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```